# Adding a class (related to tailwind) using javascript doens't work

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js

I have a button with a PLUS svg image in it. On click, I what that Plus svg to disappear. I checked in console and the function works fine, the class "visible" is removed and the class "invisible" is added. But in the UI the Plus svg doesn't disappear.
"Invisible" is a class in Tailwind that should make an item to be hidden.

```
const BtnAddEle = document.querySelector(".addEle");
const plusSvg = document.querySelector(".addElePlus");

BtnAddEle.addEventListener("click", function () {
  plusSvg.classList.remove("visible");
  plusSvg.classList.add("invisible");
});
```

Comment: What is your `tailwind.config.js`? Looks like you forgot to add JS files into `content` section

Comment: I also believe that was the main reason for it not working properly. Mentioning the JS file path in the content portion of tailwind.config.js file would solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it is not working for you is that-

To have tailwind classes to work from JS file you have to **define the path of js file** in the content portion of **tailwind.config.js** file.
Example:

```
content: ["./*.{html,js}", "./src/**/*.{html,js}"]
```

Using this, your tailwind compiler will know that you are trying to add a css class from your JS file and that class will appear in the output css file.

Content Configuration is mentioned and explained in details - [**Here [Official Documentation]**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations)

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because tailwind only adds class styles which you have used in the final CSS file

So you can do something like this

```js
const BtnAddEle = document.querySelector(".addEle");
const plusSvg = document.querySelector(".addElePlus");

BtnAddEle.addEventListener("click", function () {
  plusSvg.style.visibility = "hidden"
});
```